# Avoid JSoup generating whitespace when using replaceWith

Tags: java, html, jsoup

my goal is to turn this HTML:

```
<span style="font-family: Arial;">TEXT</span>
```

into this:

```
<arial>TEXT</arial>
```

I'm using this code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String input = "<span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">TEXT</span>";
    final Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input);
    final Tag tag = Tag.valueOf("arial");
    final Element span = document.getElementsByTag("span").get(0);
    final Element newElement = new Element(tag, "");
    newElement.html(span.html());
    span.replaceWith(newElement);
    System.out.println(document.body().children());
}
```

But my output is:

```
<arial>
 TEXT
</arial>
```

I need to avoid the whitespace surrounding the label "TEXT", but I haven't found a method or a way to specify how to generate the output without whitespaces.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I meant to remove the whitespace between <arial> and TEXT and </arial>. I'm sorry you got downvoted tough :-/

Comment: i have updated my answer can you try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String input = "<span style=\"font-family: Arial;\">TEXT</span>";
    final OutputSettings settings = new OutputSettings();
    settings.prettyPrint(false);
    final Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(input);
    document.outputSettings(settings);
    final Tag tag = Tag.valueOf("arial");
    final Element span = document.getElementsByTag("span").get(0);
    final Element newElement = new Element(tag, "");
    newElement.html(span.html());
    span.replaceWith(newElement);
    System.out.print(document.body().children());
}
```

I needed to create an OutputSettings and set prettyPrint to false. Now the output is:

```
<arial>TEXT</arial>
```

Yay!